# sending file from C# to angular1.6

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, file-transfer, arraybuffer

I need to generate a docx file using C# with client informations, It works.
Now that I have created my file, I want to send it to the Angular 1.6 client.

I found this exemple : http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2016/05/angularjs-download-files-by-sending.html

so my function is pretty much the same :

```
 public HttpResponseMessage DownloadSR(string fileName)
    {  string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/" + fileName + ".docx");
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
                file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
                ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);

                HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
                httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes.ToArray());
                httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", fileName);
                httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = filePath;
                httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                return httpResponseMessage;
            }
        }
    }
```

the JS part is different because of the `.success` part :

```
$rootScope.DL = function (filename) {


    var urlDlApi = jsHelper.getEnvBaseUrl() + 'DlApi/' + filename;
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: urlDlApi,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    }).then(
    // Response from request
        function (response) {
            headers = response.headers();
            if (true) {
                var contentType = headers['content-type'];
                var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
                var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: response.config.headers.Accept });
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
                linkElement.setAttribute("download", filename);

                var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
                    "view": window,
                    "bubbles": true,
                    "cancelable": false
                });
                linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
            }
            else {
                $scope.showErrorMessage = true;
                $rootScope.errorMessage = response.data.ErrorMessages;
            }
            $scope.isLoading = false;
        },
        // Eror from request
        function (response) {
            console.error("Erreur requete ", response);
            $scope.showErrorMessage = true;
            $scope.errorMessage = "error append, please contact site administrator";
            $scope.isLoading = false;
        }
    );
}
```

when testing C#, file.length is 84022 bytes long, 
httpResponseMessage.Content contains the 84022 Bytes.

in the javascript part, a console.log of `response` give me :

> {data: ArrayBuffer, status: 200, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", headers: ƒ, …}
>   config
>   :
>   headers
>   :
>   {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"}
>   jsonpCallbackParam
>   :
>   "callback"
>   method
>   :
>   "GET"
>   paramSerializer
>   :
>   ƒ ngParamSerializer(params)
>   responseType
>   :
>   "arraybuffer"
>   transformRequest
>   :
>   [ƒ]
>   transformResponse
>   :
>   [ƒ]
>   url
>   :
>   "/shop/download/myfile"
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Object
>   data
>   :
>   ArrayBuffer
>   byteLength
>   :
>   269
>   **proto**
>   :
>   ArrayBuffer
>   headers
>   :
>   ƒ (name)
>   arguments
>   :
>   [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (:2:14)]
>   caller
>   :
>   [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (:2:14)]
>   length
>   :
>   1
>   name
>   :
>   ""
>   prototype
>   :
>   {constructor: ƒ}
>   **proto**
>   :
>   ƒ ()
>   [[FunctionLocation]]
>   :
>   angular.js:11376
>   [[Scopes]]
>   :
>   Scopes[3]
>   status
>   :
>   200
>   statusText
>   :
>   "OK"
>   xhrStatus
>   :
>   "complete"
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Object

I wonder about the length of data : 269
it contains none of the 84022 bytes of content
network tab said that the size of this GET is 700 bytes

with this JS function, i get a file "myfile.txt". it contains :

> StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent, Headers: {
>
> x-filename: myfile
>
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>
> Content-Disposition: attachment; 
>   filename="C:\Users\tarsicius\Downloads\myfile.docx"
>
> }

So it has all the informations of the httpResponseMessage, except that the content is replace only by the type of the content :

> System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent

I need some insigth here to understand what I did wrong and make it right

thanks

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14083